# Автоматическое закрытие всплывающего окна

Tags: java, swing

Использую стандартный Popup из библиотеки swing.

```
Popup popup = PopupFactory.getSharedInstance().getPopup(frame, panel, x, y);
popup.show();
```

Как сделать, чтобы при клике юзера за пределами этого окна или при переключении на другое окно, закрывалась эта панель. Подозреваю, что нужно слушать события фокуса, но у меня не получилось.

Comment: а вы делали repaint панели после того как ее спрятали? repaint парент окна? можно еще попробовать так:
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater (
               new Runnable ()
               {
                  public void run ()
                       {
                        // прячем панель, обновляем окно
                       }
               }
               );

Comment: как вариант можно еще попробовать удалить панель с окна, варианты см. выше

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заменить Popup на JWindow. Некоторые компоненты создают всплывающую панель, которая ведет себя подобным образом. В классе PopupFactory видно, что всплывающие окна бывают:

1. light weight popup
2. medium weight popup
3. heavy weight popup

Есть метод setPopupType, в который можно передать параметр с указанием типа. Но он имеет область видимости package internal. А в реализации публичного метода

```
public Popup getPopup(Component owner, Component contents,
                          int x, int y)
```

явно прописан тип - heavy weight popup.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте воспользоваться событием onblur. Событие onblur возникает при потере объектом фокуса при переходе по клику мыши или с помощью клавиатуры.

Comment: Это GWT, а я использую Swing.